# How does FileHelpers read from stream

Tags: .net, stream, loading, filehelpers

I need to read a lot of fixed width and delimited files, big files, 800MB, 1GB... and convert the records in those files to objects. I'm looking at FileHelpers and have a question: does FileHelpers read from stream using lazy loading? Or does it read the entire file from stream first? That would make it less efficient in my case.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

FileHelpers supports large files using [FileHelperAsyncEngine](https://www.filehelpers.net/docs/html/T_FileHelpers_FileHelperAsyncEngine.htm). If you use the async engine, you will be using much less memory and will run much faster.

Here a [Read File Async example](https://www.filehelpers.net/example/QuickStart/ReadWriteRecordByRecord/)